# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupDrawingOrderHelper.getChildDrawingOrder in React Native

Tags: android, crash, react-native

Hi i am working in react native 0.61.4 and i got crashes in android  not for iOS.

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupDrawingOrderHelper.getChildDrawingOrder(ViewGroupDrawingOrderHelper.java:98)`

Android Crash only

> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27610

I have also created issue  but nothing seem to helpful

Can anybody tell me what is the actual error and how to fix this.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by understanding

[ViewGroupDrawingOrderHelper.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/ViewGroupDrawingOrderHelper.java)

The mistake i was doing that i was giving loader of `zIndex 70` in style.

that's why app was crashing on android. on iOS it was working fine. and

> by removing `zIndex 70.` from styles, my crash fixed ❤️

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep the `zIndex`, you can add the following to the `FlatList`:

```
removeClippedSubviews={false}
```

Credit to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18616#issuecomment-753623907) on a react-native issue.
Not sure how this affects performance, seems like iOS has this as `false` by default.